# How can I disable reordering my columns when I set some columns visibility to false?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, devexpress

I want to have a fixed structure of my gridview table columns. I have a radio group where you are allowed to hide some of columns, but then when I'm showing all my columns, they are reordered. I want them to keep the initial order, even if I set visibility false to some of them.
How can I do that?

Comment: how to save their initial order?

Comment: How? I used debugger and my Column's VisibleIndexes were randomly assigned

Comment: When you put your columns visibility to false, then visibleindex will be -1. Then visibleindexes are assigned with values incrementally

Comment: Even if i put that columns all to false, then all to true, visible indexes of that columns are not in order

Comment: Wellp, there is a visible index in gridview -> columns -> properties. And my columns are sorting accorting to that visible indexes